# Why HIlt can not create instance of SharedViewModel?

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-hilt

### Update 1

I changed delegate from `viewModels` to `hiltNavGraphViewModels` and it's works. Thanks to ianhanniballake's comments. But now is another issue. If app have killed (Logcat -> Terminate App), occurs exception `No destination with ID 2131296453 is on the NavController's back stack. The current destination is null` (stacktrace below). How can I restore back stack in order to `hiltNavGraphViewModels` don't fail?

```kotlin
@AndroidEntryPoint
class ScriptDetailFragment: Fragment(R.layout.component_detail_script) {

    private val viewModel: SharedViewModel by hiltNavGraphViewModels(R.id.scriptFragment)
}

@AndroidEntryPoint
class ScriptFragment : Fragment(R.layout.component_script) {

    private val viewModel: SharedViewModel by hiltNavGraphViewModels(R.id.scriptFragment)

    fun navigateToDetail(navDirection: NavDirections) {
        findNavController().navigate(navDirection)
    }
}

@HiltViewModel
class SharedViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val componentWrapper: ComponentWrapper
) : ViewModel() {

}
```

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.8.0'

    implementation 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.38'
    implementation("androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-fragment:1.0.0")
    kapt 'com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:2.38'
    kapt 'androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0'

    implementation "androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.5.1"
    implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.5.4"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.5.3"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.5.3"
}
```

```
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No destination with ID 2131296453 is on the NavController's back stack. The current destination is null
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.getBackStackEntry(NavController.kt:2209)
        at *.pages.departure.ScriptFragment$special$$inlined$hiltNavGraphViewModels$1.invoke(HiltNavGraphViewModelLazy.kt:49)
        at *.pages.departure.ScriptFragment$special$$inlined$hiltNavGraphViewModels$1.invoke(Unknown Source:0)
        at kotlin.SynchronizedLazyImpl.getValue(LazyJVM.kt:74)
        at *.pages.departure.ScriptFragment$special$$inlined$hiltNavGraphViewModels$3.invoke(HiltNavGraphViewModelLazy.kt:57)
        at *.pages.departure.ScriptFragment$special$$inlined$hiltNavGraphViewModels$3.invoke(Unknown Source:0)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelLazy.getValue(ViewModelLazy.kt:47)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelLazy.getValue(ViewModelLazy.kt:35)
        at *.pages.departure.ScriptFragment.getViewModel(ScriptFragment.kt:15)
        at *.pages.departure.ScriptFragment.onViewCreated(ScriptFragment.kt:20)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performViewCreated(Fragment.java:3128)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:552)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:261)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStore.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStore.java:113)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1433)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:2977)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchViewCreated(FragmentManager.java:2888)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performViewCreated(Fragment.java:3129)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:552)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:261)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStore.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStore.java:113)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1433)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:2977)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:2895)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:263)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:351)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:248)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1335)
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:7043)
```

activity_main.xml

```
    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/nav_host"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        tools:context=".screens.MainActivity" />
```

MainActivity.ki

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        _binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        configureNavHost()
    }

    override fun onSupportNavigateUp() = navController.navigateUp() || super.onSupportNavigateUp()

    private fun configureNavHost() {
        val resId = if (dsr.isFirstLaunch.value) R.id.welcomeFragment else R.id.webViewFragment
        navController = (supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host) as NavHostFragment).navController
        navController.navInflater.inflate(R.navigation.nav_graph).let { graph ->
            graph.setStartDestination(resId)
            navController.graph = graph
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So is `ScriptFragment` the parent fragment of `ScriptDetailFragment`? Can you include the code in `ScriptFragment` that adds your `ScriptDetailFragment`? Also please include the entire stacktrace of your exception.

Comment: @ianhanniballake added stacktrace. `ScriptFragment` opens detail through `findNavController().navigate()`.

Comment: Then your parent fragment is not `ScriptFragment`, it is the `NavHostFragment`, which doesn't know anything about Hilt. Is there a reason you aren't using a [navigation graph scoped Hilt ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-jetpack#viewmodel-navigation) that both fragment can access?

Comment: @ianhanniballake I need to ViewModel destroyed when `ScriptFragment` closed. Because chain `script->detail` uses in two places and influence to different sources. Now I tried `by hiltNavGraphViewModels()`, ViewModel doesn't destroyed like and `by activityViewModels()`. Can I scoped this?

Comment: What navigation destination ID are you passing into `hiltNavGraphViewModels()`? If you are using the ID of your `ScriptFragment`, then it *would* be destroyed when `ScriptFragment` is popped off the back stack.

Comment: @ianhanniballake I thought that `navGraphId` is entire navigation layout or it root id. Seems work like I want with fragment id. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @ianhanniballake may you check update post, please?

Comment: Are you manually calling `setGraph` on your `NavController`? Or do you use `app:navGraph` in XML on your `FragmentContainerView` that includes your `NavHostFragment`? Please include the relevant code in your activity / activity XML

Comment: @ianhanniballake I choose a start destination and set it in MainActivity, code included

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the app is killed and then restarted, the Navigation graph and the back stack will be reset. This means that any fragments or destinations that were on the back stack will be removed, and the `NavController` will no longer be able to find them.

In order to restore the back stack and avoid the exception, you can use the `onSaveInstanceState()` method in `Fragment` or `Activity` to save the state of the `NavController` and the back stack. This will allow to restore the stored state when the app is restarted.

Example of implementation in a `Fragment`:

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MyFragment : Fragment() {

    private val navController by lazy { findNavController() }

    override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
        // Save the state of the NavController and the back stack
        navController.saveState(outState)
    }

    override fun onViewStateRestored(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewStateRestored(savedInstanceState)
        // Restore the state of the NavController and the back stack
        savedInstanceState?.let { navController.restoreState(it) }
    }
}
```

With this implementation, the state of the `NavController` and the back stack will be saved when the app is killed and restored when the app is restarted, allowing the `hiltNavGraphViewModels()` function to find the correct destination and avoid the exception.